# Using jquery's .load() doesnt run the script on the loaded page even without a selector expression

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my code in index.html where i call .load to load the entire artists.html
into the div with the id scripting. This is all happening in index.html and the page is loading fine.

```
  $j("#artists").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
         $j( "#scriptin" ).load( "artists.html" );
```

The problem is with the javascript inside artists.html. It does not seem to execute when the page loads after the calling of .load(). It works fine when i open it with the direct link.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.animate').mouseenter(function() {

                    $(this).css("opacity",1);

                })
                $('.animate').mouseleave(function() {

                    $(this).css("opacity",0.8);

                })

            })
            </script>
```

Comment: How are you loading the page using AJAX? Are you using jQuery to append the resulting response to the DOM somewhere? Are you dynamically loading an iframe? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Seconded. Please let us know if there's anything on the page other than the script tag, and where each element (`#artists`, `.animate`, etc) is located. HTML samples would be great.

Comment: Im using the .load function. The rest of the code is irrelevant. The page (artists.html) loads when i call the load function but the script (the one iv posted) doesnt run. It does run when i directly open the link. Iv updated to add the html.( tho i think it is irrelevant to the question.)

Comment: Do you load a jQuery library before that script? What's in a console?

Answer (score 0):

Does your script in artists.html reside inside of the head tag on that page? From the jquery documentation:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as html,
>   title, or head elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

Move your scripts to the body of your artists.html file and the scripts should get run as you have things defined there.

Comment: Tried that. Didnt work. All the scripts are in the body.